HTML / CSS Rotation - weird glitching?
When you remove the
@keyframes rotate {
    100% { transform: rotateZ(360deg); } 
}

block, you will see my construct as it's intended, but when you paste it back in, everything changes its position and nothing looks like it's supposed to anymore.


#fluegelr {
  left: 52%;
  top: 53%;
}

#stabr {
  left: 50%;
  top: 55%;
}

#fluegell {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  left: 41%;
  top: 55%;
}

#stabl {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  left: 46.4%;
  top: 55%;
}

#fluegelh {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: 46.9%;
  top: 43%;
}

#stabh {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: 48.5%;
  top: 52%;
}

#fluegelu {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  left: 45.9%;
  top: 65%;
}

#stabu {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  left: 48.5%;
  top: 58%;
}

.fluegel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 8rem 8rem 0 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.stab {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 58px;
  background-color: black;
}

#f1 {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 60s;
}

#centerCircle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 49.5%;
  top: 53.8%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
<div id="f1">
  <div class="fluegel" id="fluegelr"></div>
  <div class="stab" id="stabr"></div>
  <div class="fluegel" id="fluegell"></div>
  <div class="stab" id="stabl"></div>
  <div class="fluegel" id="fluegelh"></div>
  <div class="stab" id="stabh"></div>
  <div class="fluegel" id="fluegelu"></div>
  <div class="stab" id="stabu"></div>
</div>



<div id="centerCircle"></div>



I do not know, maybe it is because of the "%".

What effect are you trying to achieve?

Also rotateZ is unusual... what is it being used for?

What point are you wanting it to rotate around, is it the Center of the black circle?

And honestly, an SVG would probably be more appropriate here.

Its because height of #f1 is 0. I recommend you to use code below.


#fluegelr {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-1.5rem);
}

#stabr {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#fluegell {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#stabl {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

#fluegelh {
  transform: translateY(-1.5rem) rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

#stabh {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

#fluegelu {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

#stabu {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: top left;
}


.fluegel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 8rem 8rem 0 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stab {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: black;
}

#f1 {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 60s;
  width: 325px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

#centerCircle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    100% { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg); } 
}
<div id="f1">
    <div class="fluegel" id="fluegelr"></div>
    <div class="stab" id="stabr"></div>
    <div class="fluegel" id="fluegell"></div>
    <div class="stab" id="stabl"></div>
    <div class="fluegel" id="fluegelh"></div>
    <div class="stab" id="stabh"></div>
    <div class="fluegel" id="fluegelu"></div>
    <div class="stab" id="stabu"></div>
  
    <div id="centerCircle"></div>
</div>



